# Создание представления (view) в symfony

Tags: sql, view, symfony

Есть два запроса сделанные в `sql`:

```
 CREATE VIEW faces_v AS SELECT
   full_name, 
   (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(birth_date))-(RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE, 5)<RIGHT(birth_date, 5)
   ) AS age
 FROM faces;



SELECT * FROM faces_v WHERE age > 27;
```

Подкажите, как реализовать это в `symfony (doctrine)`, чтобы и создание вьюхи и выборка данных из этой вьюхи были в одном методе?

Comment: Непонятно зачем вам представление, если вы его создаете и используете в одном методе. Тогда вам еще нужно добавить третий запрос, который будет удалять представление. :-)
Просто напишите один запрос, который будет решать проблему.

Ну, и поскольку вам, вероятно, придется передавать параметр отбора (age > ?), то лучше использовать хранимую процедуру, вместо представления.

Comment: Поддержу @SergeyMoiseenko: глупо таким заниматься. Но если действительно нужно, то надо в репозитории вытаскивать конкретное соединение (которое рвет кроссплатформенность между СУБД), через него уже кидать нативный SQL.